# WPF MVVM Binding Image Control to Image in Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an Image in my resources I want to display based on an input text string where I am using a converter, what is the way to implement this as it is not displaying in my application.

in my converter EstateCodetoEstateImageConverter I have

```
 return  Resources.Customer1EstateHeaderImage;
```

In my XAML I have

```
   <Image Source="{Binding EstateSheet.EstateCode, Converter={StaticResource EstateCodetoEstateImageConverter1}}" Stretch="Fill" Width="189" Height="112" />
```

My understanding is that binding to the source needs the file Path name and not the actual resource, how should I do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a typical WPF application you would not put images into `Resources.resx` and access them by the `Resources` class. Instead you would just add the image files to your Visual Studio project (perhaps in a folder called Images) and set their `Build Action` to `Resource`. Now you are able to access them by means of a [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx), and the Convert method of your converter might look like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    object result = null;

    switch ((EstateCode)value)
    {
        case EstateCode.EstateCode1:
            result = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Estate1.jpg"));
            break;
        case EstateCode.EstateCode2:
            result = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Estate2.jpg"));
            break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that worked, Thank you . marked as answer