# Adding image from Resources to XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, visual-studio-2013

I need help adding image to XAML.

I added my image to Resources under tab Images.

I have an image there (in Canvas) and on Properties I click Source. From the drop-down I can select my `Image001.png` so that's great. When I click it it adds to Source `pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Image001.png` but when I run my program it doesn't show.

Also, when I try to set a background to my canvas:

```
<Canvas.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/frame.png"/>
</Canvas.Background>
```

It gives a runtime error.

Help please.

Comment: make sure that the Image001.png is a resource and that it does not copy. interesting that your source shows like that. After you switch it to resource, set your source to null, then reset it to Image001 again and see if that fixes it

Comment: Yes, it is definitely a resource and I have resetted it, removed it, added it back 3 times. Still doesn't work :(

Comment: Is it a typo that you set the ImageSource of the ImageBrush to frame.png instead of Image001.png?

Comment: No. For my image (in Canvas) I want to set my Image001 and for my Canvas.Background I want to set frame. It finds nothing in my Resources folder.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23738149/1136211) might be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Robert said: Set the build action of the image to "Resource" under Properties and then use the following syntax:

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="/YourNamespace;component/Resources/frame.png"/>
```