# Where is the resource path from my image?

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm trying to retrieve the BitmapImage from an resource image, but I can't figure the correct path to archive it, I've searched I have to access by using "pack://" I didn't figure out this syntax:

```
                var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyImages/start.png");
                var bitmap = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

For requirement reasons, I can't make the images content which would force to me to copy them when deployed instead of embedded into the PE.

thanks

Comment: It should work, provided that the image file `start.png` is located in a folder `MyImages` in your Visual Studio project, and that its `Build Action` is set to `Resource`. If you are probably asking about image resources in `Resources.resx`, you might take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23738149/1136211).

Comment: yes, you were right, I didn't pay attention, when you mentioned I went make sure the path was correct. I ran it and it works great. Thanks. Make it an answer and I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as expected, provided that the image file `start.png` is located in a folder `MyImages` in your Visual Studio project, and that its `Build Action` is set to `Resource`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
BitmapImage WarningIcon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/My.Assembly.Name;component/Icons/Warning_32x32.png", UriKind.Relative));
```